# Books in different languages combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

I'm currently working on an old combinatorics problem from my university, which is as follows:
Let there be 9 English books, 7 French books and 10 German books. How many ways are there to choose 7 books from them, so that every language is represented?

I've found some similar asked problems but I'm still not sure what the correct answer might be...

I thought that I could handle it similar to a lottery problem, where for example the ways to get 1 out of 6 right when there are 45 numbers is: $\binom{6}{1}\binom{39}{5}$

So I came up with the answer:
$\binom{7}{3}\binom{19}{4} + \binom{7}{4}\binom{19}{3} + \binom{7}{5}\binom{19}{2} + \binom{7}{6}\binom{19}{1} + \binom{7}{7}\binom{19}{0}$

I'm not very confident in the validity of this answer, can you help me?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @AnotherUser Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderGrabner Are the books in same category same or distinct ? For example , are these $9$ English books same as one another or distinct from one another ?

Comment: @SalmonFish I think they are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the books in same category are the same as one another , we can use ordinary generating functions to calculate. It is said that every book type must be represented , then

- Generating function for $9$ English books where there is at least one book : $$\frac{x(1-x^9)}{1-x}=x+x^2+x^3+...+x^9$$
- Generating function for $7$ French books where there is at least one book: $$\frac{x(1-x^7)}{1-x}=x+x^2+x^3+...+x^7$$
- Generating function for $10$ German books where there is at least one book : $$\frac{x(1-x^{10})}{1-x}=x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{10}$$

Now , find the coefficient of $x^7$ in the expansion of them such that [EXPANSION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%28x%281-x%5E9%29%2F%281-x%29%29%28x%281-x%5E7%29%2F%281-x%29%29%28x%281-x%5E10%29%2F%281-x%29%29)

So , the answer is $15$